# OpAmp or voltage divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, voltage-divider

I want to measure battery level within my circuit with an ADC. I've been said to scale the voltage to Vcc and use it as Vref of the ADC. I've thought of two options for doing it: a voltage divider with resistors or an op amp. I want to know which one is better and why.

Comment: You have to define "better". Is cheaper, simpler better, etc?

Comment: @WesleyLee all relevant aspects matter I think

Comment: Cheaper, simpler, more efficient, less battery consuming, etc

Comment: No one is going to write chapter and verse on your whim. There are textbooks out there that, broadly speaking, cover the area. There are circuits you can google up. There are blogs. Etc. You have no right to expect long discourses made to order for you. Especially without seeing some effort on your part to narrow the scope. I've already written more than you. And that fact is already a sad comment itself on the state of affairs of your question. Write more, talk about your situation in detail. Treat others with the respect you'd expect, by giving more than you expect to get back in return.